# How to install cursive fonts for matplotlib: Font family ['cursive'] not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

When trying to run a script (given below in the minimal working example) on Ubuntu 20.04 that uses the cursive fonts in `matplotlib` I am getting the `matplotlib` warnings:

```
findfont: Font family ['cursive'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
```

which tells me that I don't have any of the cursive fonts that `matplotlib` wants to use for [the cursive font family](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/text/text_props.html#default-font).
This seems to be confirmed in the minimal failing example below when none of the cursive fonts can be found by `matplotlib`'s font manager or by `fc-list`

```
# on my local machine
$ fc-list : family | grep -i "chancery\|textile\|sand\|script\|felipa\|cursive"
URW Chancery L
Free Chancery
```

How can I programatically find and install these fonts on Ubuntu? I know that I could hunt down free versions on the internet, but if I wanted to get them on a Docker image how can I install them through a CLI API like `apt-get`?

### Minimal Failing Example

For the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
        fontconfig \
        fonts-dejavu \
        fonts-freefont-ttf \
        python3 \
        python3-dev \
        python3-pip \
        python3-venv \
        vim && \
        apt-get -y autoclean && \
        apt-get -y autoremove && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip setuptools wheel && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir "matplotlib~=3.3" && \
    python3 -m pip list && \
    python3 -c "import matplotlib.pyplot" # generate font list cache

ENV MPLCONFIGDIR /tmp/.config # make writeable to non-root user

WORKDIR /code

COPY example.py example.py
```

with `example.py` of

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager


def make_plot(font_family):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
    y = np.square(x)
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.semilogy()

    ax.set_xlabel("$x$")
    ax.set_ylabel("$x^2$")
    ax.set_title(f"Default matplotlib settings for {font_family} font family")

    return fig, ax


def main():

    image_types = ["pdf", "png"]
    for font_family in ["sans-serif", "serif", "cursive"]:
        plt.rcParams.update({"font.family": font_family})
        fig, ax = make_plot(font_family=font_family)

        for type in image_types:
            fig.savefig(f"family_{font_family}.{type}")

    cursive_family = matplotlib.rcParams["font.cursive"]
    print(f"\nmatplotlib cursive family: {cursive_family}")
    tff_fonts = sorted(
        set([font.name for font in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist])
    )
    afm_fonts = sorted(
        set([font.name for font in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.afmlist])
    )
    all_fonts = sorted(set([*tff_fonts, *afm_fonts]))
    print(f"\ntff fonts: {tff_fonts}")
    print(f"\nafm fonts: {afm_fonts}")
    print(f"\nall fonts: {all_fonts}")
    found_cursive_fonts = [font for font in cursive_family if font in all_fonts]
    print(f"\nfound cursive fonts: {found_cursive_fonts}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

if built with

```
docker build . \
--pull \
-f Dockerfile \
-t matplotlib-cursive-fonts-question:debug-local
```

and then run with

```
$ docker run --rm --user 1000:1000 -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD matplotlib-cursive-fonts-question:debug-local /bin/bash -c "python3 /code/example.py"
findfont: Font family ['cursive'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
findfont: Font family ['cursive'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.

matplotlib cursive family: ['Apple Chancery', 'Textile', 'Zapf Chancery', 'Sand', 'Script MT', 'Felipa', 'cursive']

tff fonts: ['DejaVu Math TeX Gyre', 'DejaVu Sans', 'DejaVu Sans Display', 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'DejaVu Serif', 'DejaVu Serif Display', 'FreeMono', 'FreeSans', 'FreeSerif', 'STIXGeneral', 'STIXNonUnicode', 'STIXSizeFiveSym', 'STIXSizeFourSym', 'STIXSizeOneSym', 'STIXSizeThreeSym', 'STIXSizeTwoSym', 'cmb10', 'cmex10', 'cmmi10', 'cmr10', 'cmss10', 'cmsy10', 'cmtt10']

afm fonts: ['Computer Modern', 'Courier', 'Helvetica', 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic', 'ITC Bookman', 'ITC Zapf Chancery', 'ITC Zapf Dingbats', 'New Century Schoolbook', 'Palatino', 'Symbol', 'Times', 'Utopia', 'ZapfDingbats']

all fonts: ['Computer Modern', 'Courier', 'DejaVu Math TeX Gyre', 'DejaVu Sans', 'DejaVu Sans Display', 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'DejaVu Serif', 'DejaVu Serif Display', 'FreeMono', 'FreeSans', 'FreeSerif', 'Helvetica', 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic', 'ITC Bookman', 'ITC Zapf Chancery', 'ITC Zapf Dingbats', 'New Century Schoolbook', 'Palatino', 'STIXGeneral', 'STIXNonUnicode', 'STIXSizeFiveSym', 'STIXSizeFourSym', 'STIXSizeOneSym', 'STIXSizeThreeSym', 'STIXSizeTwoSym', 'Symbol', 'Times', 'Utopia', 'ZapfDingbats', 'cmb10', 'cmex10', 'cmmi10', 'cmr10', 'cmss10', 'cmsy10', 'cmtt10']

found cursive fonts: []
```

and

```
docker run --rm --user 1000:1000 -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD matplotlib-cursive-fonts-question:debug-local /bin/bash -c "fc-list : family | grep -i 'chancery\|textile\|sand\|script\|felipa\|cursive'"
```

returns nothing.

### Questions

How can I programatically find and install the required cursive fonts for `matplotlib` (on Ubuntu 20.04)?

### Relevant links

- [GitHub Gist that contains all of this code for this Stack Overflow question](https://gist.github.com/matthewfeickert/0812306c9b012d286995c83395f70df4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems there is no clear way to get these fonts from any Ubuntu PPA, what can be done instead is to just directly download [Felipa](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Felipa?query=Felipa), one of the cursive font family fonts, from Google Fonts. This is what the `maptlotlib` team does in the [`mpl-docker` testing Docker image](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl-docker/blob/9272c82023aa5b84584a37eee7a2fbd0d4663491/Dockerfile#L35-L38).

So for a **programmatic** solution on my local machine what I can do is just

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/fonts/truetype/felipa
wget --no-clobber https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/felipa/Felipa-Regular.ttf?raw=true -O ~/.local/share/fonts/truetype/felipa/Felipa-Regular.ttf
fc-cache --force --verbose # rebuild font cache for system
rm -rf ~/.cache/matplotlib/* # remove the matplotlib cache to force rebuild
```

and while it isn't required I also made a symlink to where the rest of my fonts are for bookkeeping

```sh
sudo ln -s "${HOME}/.local/share/fonts/truetype/felipa" /usr/share/fonts/truetype/felipa
```

Of course, while this is programmatic, if you're on a local machine and have interactive capabilities it is probably better/easier to just visit [the Google Fonts page for Felipa](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Felipa?query=Felipa), download the font family zip file locally and extract it, and then open the `Felipa-Regular.ttf` with the [Ubuntu font manager](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/font-manager)  and let it install it for you.

To give a reproducible example of this working I've edited the original Dockerfile to `wget` Felipa as decribed above and then also create a non-root user "docker" to both have the container run as non-root by default and to avoid the problems of having a `HOME`-less user when run with `--user 1000:1000`. There are ways to make this Dockerfile much more compact, but I'm going for readability in this example over size optimization.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
        fontconfig \
        fonts-dejavu \
        fonts-freefont-ttf \
        python3 \
        python3-dev \
        python3-pip \
        python3-venv \
        vim \
        wget && \
        apt-get -y autoclean && \
        apt-get -y autoremove && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip setuptools wheel && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir "matplotlib~=3.3" && \
    python3 -m pip list

# Create user "docker"
RUN useradd -m docker && \
    cp /root/.bashrc /home/docker/
ENV HOME /home/docker

# felipa provides a cursive font
RUN mkdir -p "${HOME}/.local/share/fonts/truetype/felipa" && \
    wget --no-clobber "https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/felipa/Felipa-Regular.ttf?raw=true" -O "${HOME}/.local/share/fonts/truetype/felipa/Felipa-Regular.ttf" && \
    ln -s "${HOME}/.local/share/fonts/truetype/felipa" /usr/share/fonts/truetype/felipa && \
    fc-cache --force --verbose

WORKDIR /code

COPY example.py example.py

# give non-root user docker ownership of files
RUN chown -R --from=root docker /home/docker && \
    chown -R --from=root docker /code
USER docker

# Create font list cache and config dir
RUN python3 -c "import matplotlib.pyplot"
```

rebuilding this Docker image as before then allows for the following to run without warnings or errors

```
$ docker run --rm -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD matplotlib-cursive-fonts-question:debug-local /bin/bash -c "python3 /code/example.py"

matplotlib cursive family: ['Apple Chancery', 'Textile', 'Zapf Chancery', 'Sand', 'Script MT', 'Felipa', 'cursive']

tff fonts: ['DejaVu Math TeX Gyre', 'DejaVu Sans', 'DejaVu Sans Display', 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'DejaVu Serif', 'DejaVu Serif Display', 'Felipa', 'FreeMono', 'FreeSans', 'FreeSerif', 'STIXGeneral', 'STIXNonUnicode', 'STIXSizeFiveSym', 'STIXSizeFourSym', 'STIXSizeOneSym', 'STIXSizeThreeSym', 'STIXSizeTwoSym', 'cmb10', 'cmex10', 'cmmi10', 'cmr10', 'cmss10', 'cmsy10', 'cmtt10']

afm fonts: ['Computer Modern', 'Courier', 'Helvetica', 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic', 'ITC Bookman', 'ITC Zapf Chancery', 'ITC Zapf Dingbats', 'New Century Schoolbook', 'Palatino', 'Symbol', 'Times', 'Utopia', 'ZapfDingbats']

all fonts: ['Computer Modern', 'Courier', 'DejaVu Math TeX Gyre', 'DejaVu Sans', 'DejaVu Sans Display', 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'DejaVu Serif', 'DejaVu Serif Display', 'Felipa', 'FreeMono', 'FreeSans', 'FreeSerif', 'Helvetica', 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic', 'ITC Bookman', 'ITC Zapf Chancery', 'ITC Zapf Dingbats', 'New Century Schoolbook', 'Palatino', 'STIXGeneral', 'STIXNonUnicode', 'STIXSizeFiveSym', 'STIXSizeFourSym', 'STIXSizeOneSym', 'STIXSizeThreeSym', 'STIXSizeTwoSym', 'Symbol', 'Times', 'Utopia', 'ZapfDingbats', 'cmb10', 'cmex10', 'cmmi10', 'cmr10', 'cmss10', 'cmsy10', 'cmtt10']

found cursive fonts: ['Felipa']
```

producing this plot for `family_cursive.png`:

[image]

Comment: I would now say that creating `~/.local/share/fonts/truetype/felipa` is excessive and one should just put the fonts under `~/.local/share/fonts/`.